# Can I delete the M-WIN-L-12.1.0-* folder?

Tags: installation

My hard drive is running out of space.

Can I delete the M-WIN-L-12.1.0-* folder without impacting Mathematica in any way?

It looks like it just setup files but is 4GB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to delete this folder as it only contains the setup files.  But... you might want to copy the setup files to a long-term backup medium instead of simply deleting them in case you want to reinstall this exact version in the indeterminate future.

Be aware that WRI does not necessarily keep all versions of all installers available on the Wolfram user portal.  Also, depending upon your license and support agreements you might lose access to the download at some point while retaining license to use the software (although WRI support could probably help you out in such a case).  A backup copy might save you some hassle in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and thanks for the great tip too.